# Need help to understand the downvotes in SHA-256 question and answer

Tags: discussion, down-votes

The question is [here](https://monero.stackexchange.com/questions/2513/computing-sha256-inside-simplewallet-cpp).  There was obviously immediate interest, due to quick down-voting in the first hour the question existed.  Please help me understand.

My technical prowess isn't the best, but it appears that the person asking the question has asked very intelligent questions in the past, so what is it about this question that would make it get down-voted?

Also, why is the answer down-voted multiple times?  It's not like there is any indication that it's completely wrong.  Is it?  There are no comments, aside from a clarification by the asker.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is basicly everything wrong with that question and here is why I closed it:

1. It's not about monero in first place, but a programming question asking how to perform a sha256() in an existing C++ project.
2. It's not showing any research being made prior asking. Google *cpp sha256* yields a lot of examples.
3. The author admits he is new to C++, answers are most likely impossible because people would have to start with absolute basics on C++ programming, linking libraries and maybe even compiling the modified project.

I've chosen the *too broad* closure reason, because of (3).

---

Edit, and for the answer: it was confusing sha256 with bitcoin hashing, but you really cant blame her because this question was asked on monero stack exchange and not on a programmers board.

Answer (score 3):

My guess is that the question was downvoted by someone who felt the sha256  question was off topic. Indeed it does appear to be more about coding than Monero specifically despite the authors comment which elaborates on his intent:

> Sha256 is a standard hashing algorithm. Regardless of whether it is broken of not, it should be available. I am aware that Monero's mining algorithm is not the same as Bitcoin's, but mind you that there are many uses for hashing functions besides mining. I just want to compute sha256 of a string, nothing more.

I not one of the people who downvoted the answer,  but it might be related to the backdoor allegation without any evidence to support it. The downvoted answer clearly does not attempt to address the question.